# Cannot remove google account from Samsung android phone. Remove button greyed out

Tags: samsung, sync, google-account, delete, disable-app

I cannot remove my google account from my android phone. Samsung XCover 4s Android 10.
This is a work phone and I only used my account to download whatsapp for work communication group.

I have deleted whatapp App.  I understand how to go to  -settings -account-tap on the gmail address I want to remove.  The problem is the *Remove button* is greyed out and diabled.

I can sign out of this device out from my laptop but all my contacts remain on the phone and my google account still on the phone.

I have tried clearing data in playstore, google etc.  I have signed in, signed out.  Sync ON then OFF.  I keep going back and the button is still not activated.

I really need help with this.  It is a privacy issue.

Comment: If it is a work account that Google account may allow your company to administer your device and therefore you can't disable the account. You should ask the admins of your company to remove your device from their device list, may be that allows you to remove the account.

Comment: Thank you Robert. Yes perhaps that is it. It is definitely encrypted with company securities and policies. I might need to get the phone reconfigured.  Will give it a go. I appreciate your reply. As I tried everything else it must be something outside the standard fixes. 
Audrey

Comment: You can check in Settings -> Security -> Apps for device Administration which apps can manage your device. One should be from "Google for Work" or something like that. Not sure if it is possible to disable the app as administration app in this dialog.